# Error in exception handler after app::abort() in application after filter

Tags: php, laravel-4

When I'm trying to use `app::abort($code)` in Laravel 4, the following error appears:

> Error in exception handler: in ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:875

The app::after filter simply calls `app::abort(401)`

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    app::abort(401);
});
```

Which in turn goes here:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if($code === 403)
    {
        return Error::forbidden();
    }

    elseif($code === 401)
    {
        return Error::unauthorized();
    }

    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Calling my error class

```
class Error
{
    public static function notFound()
    {
        return static::dispatch('/errors/not-found');
    }

    public static function forbidden()
    {
        return static::dispatch('/errors/forbidden');
    }

    public static function unauthorized()
    {
        return static::dispatch('/errors/unauthorized');
    }

    private static function dispatch($url)
    {
        return Route::dispatch(Request::create($url))->getContent();
    }
}
```

With the route, simply calling the controller which only sets a title and the content on the layout.

This all goes well, until the request has finished.

A post on the laravel forums pointed towards a database error. I highly doubt this, since all errors cause the same thing and when called as-is, it works fine.

Trying to update with composer didn't really do anything and dumping the autoload using artisan and composer didn't work either.

Does anyone happen to know why this error occurs and possibly how to fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After asking in the SO chat, changing the === to == resolved the issue after the [following comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16188156#16188156):

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if($code == 403)
    {
        return Error::forbidden();
    }

    elseif($code == 401)
    {
        return Error::unauthorized();
    }

    Log::error($exception);
})
```